# mongodump --oplog freeze when "writing captured oplog to "

Tags: database, mongodb, backup

In my cluster I have one primary and one secondary (also one arbiter).
I using mongodump for backups:

```
mongodump --host $dbhost --port $dbport -u $dbuser -p $dbpassword  --oplog --gzip
```

Dumping tables looks good, but when it comes to writing oplog - bash just freeze and doesnt finish task - only when I send interrupt signal it overcomes it.

Without `--oplog` flag it runs well.

The oplog is quite big ~nearly 50GB because my db runs for very long time, but the primary and secondary have the same size of oplog and when backups are created no data is written.
Do you know where the problem can be? I checked configuration twice, search in internet and now I have completely no idea whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I just make sure that all data is consistent between primary and secondary, then I resised oplog to smaller size and works.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the oplog is 5GB (~1000 entries) and it took ~20 minutes to finish `writing captured oplog to` step (mongo 4.0.3)